# assoc-equivalent procedure not functioning properly

Tags: scheme, associative-array, r5rs

I am attempting to write a procedure similar to Scheme's assoc. The only difference between the two, is that I want my procedure only to return the value related to the key given, where as assoc gives the entire pair (key . value). Here is my procedure:

```
(define alist '((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3)))

(define (search-list key list)
  (cond ((null? key) #f)
        ((eq? (caar list) key) (cdar list))
        ((null? (cdr list)) #f)
        (else search-list key (cdr list))))
```

I seem to be on the right track -- (search-list 'a alist) returns 1. However, when testing with (search-list 'b alist), this is my output: ((b . 2) (c . 3))

I cannot understand why my procedure does not function as I intend it to. I would be very happy if you could point out the error in my procedure. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the call (or the *missing call* rather) to search-list on the last line. Since this was not wrapped in parentheses, the procedure was never recursively called, and the procedure returned (cdr list) instead of (search-list key (cdr list)). This code works as intended:

```
(define alist '((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3)))

(define (search-list key list)
  (cond ((null? key) #f)
        ((eq? (caar list) key) (cdar list))
        ((null? (cdr list)) #f)
        (else (search-list key (cdr list)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You found your error, but I would suggest other changes:

1) you should check if the list is empty before using `caar` and the like, because your procedure will fail when called with an empty list.

2) OTOH, there's no need to check if key is null.

3) In Scheme you shouldn't use `list` as a parameter name in order not to shadow the procedure `list`.

So I would go for

```
(define (search-list key lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) #f)
    ((eq? key (caar lst)) (cdar lst))
    (else (search-list key (cdr lst)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't want exactly the behavior of `assq` (which is `assoc` using `eq?` not `equal?`) but you could still use `assq` in the implementation:

```
(define (search-list key lst)
  (cond ((assq key lst) => cdr)
        (else #f)))

> (search-list 'b '((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3)))
2
```

Also, your existing code will have trouble with an a list of `'()` because `caar` will fail.  Usually in recursive algorithms the base case, which is `(null? lst)` in your case, is tested first.